# How to make three finger drag in python on OS X with pyautogui?

Tags: pyautogui

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyAutoGUI

Here it lists all the available actions that could be made with the library, but it doesn't list double finger and triple finger scroll. Since these actions are essential for OS X, I'm sure they have included that in the library.

So how do we access three finger drag?

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
pyautogui.keyDown('ctrl')
pyautogui.press('right')
pyautogui.keyUp('ctrl')
```

Comment: perhaps a cleaner way to do this: pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl, 'right')